# Remove Text Over a Placeholder in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a dilution calculator that works with no issues. However, there is always a "0" over the placeholder in the textfield for Container Size and Dilution Ratio. I don't mind the "0", I actually want a "0" there. But I have to erase it every time I tap on the textfield to input a number. Even if I remove the placeholder it's still there. How do I make it so that I don't have to keep erasing the "0" every time I want to input a number but keep the placeholder.

```
struct CalculatorView: View {
    
    @State private var containerSize = 0
    @State private var dilutionRatio = 0
    @State private var totalProduct = 0.0
    @State private var totalWater = 0.0
    
    @FocusState private var amountIsFocused: Bool
    
    @FocusState private var focusedInput: Field?
    
    func totalProductAmount() -> Double {
        let firstValue = Double(containerSize)
        let secondValue = Double(dilutionRatio + 1)

        let totalProduct = Double(firstValue / secondValue)

    return totalProduct
    }

    func totalWaterAmount() -> Double {
        let firstValue = Double(containerSize)
        let secondValue = Double(dilutionRatio + 1)
        let totalProduct = Double(firstValue / secondValue)
        let totalWater = Double(firstValue - totalProduct)

    return totalWater
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image("Logo")
                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            
            HStack {

 //Container Size
                ZStack {
                    Image("Container Size (Oz)")
                        .padding(.vertical, -15)
                    TextField("", value: $containerSize, format: .number)
                        .frame(width: 200.0, height: 60.0)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 50, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        .focused($amountIsFocused)
                        .focused($focusedInput, equals: .containerSize)

                }
            }
//Dilution Ratio
            ZStack {
                Image("Dilution Ratio - 2")
                    .padding(.vertical, -10)
                TextField("", value: $dilutionRatio, format: .number)
                    .frame(width: 200.0, height: 60.0)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 50, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .focused($amountIsFocused)
                    .focused($focusedInput, equals: .dilutionRatio)


            }
//Go Button
            Button(action: {
                totalProduct = totalProductAmount()
                totalWater = totalWaterAmount()
                amountIsFocused = false

            }, label: {
                Image("Go Button")
            })
//Results
            HStack{
                
                ZStack {
                    Image("Total Product (Oz)")
                    Text("\(totalProduct, specifier: "%.1f")")
                        .font(Font.system(size: 60, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
                ZStack {
                    Image("Total Water (Oz)")
                    Text("\(totalWater, specifier: "%.1f")")
                        .font(Font.system(size: 60, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make containerSize and dilutionRatio an optional Int with no default value.

```
@State private var containerSize: Int?
@State private var dilutionRatio: Int?

TextField("0", value: $containerSize ?? "", format: .number)
```